# How does initial view controller work in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I've got the `MainViewController` which I set as initial `ViewController`. But in the `AppDelegate` I check if the user is logged (I check if there's some data saved) and if it's not, I set a new initial `ViewController` which is the `LoginViewController`.
`BankVault` is what I use to save data, it's a class.

```
 if !BankVault.load() {

        print("Bank not found!")
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tutorialPageViewController") as! TutorialViewController

        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

My question is: Does it load the first initial viewcontroller and then the LoginViewController or it load immediately the Loginviewcontroller?

Comment: You are not setting initial view controller. Initial view controller is just a special controller in a storyboard.

Comment: Check this..https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2014/07/login-signup-screen-tutorial-xcode-6-swift-ios-8-json/

Answer (score 1):

there is a function to initialise the [instantiateInitialViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateInitialViewController)
separately for this kind of scenario only.

In your case , it will just initialize the storyboard with the line

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

> If you want , you can instantiate the initial VC by the other method
>   call or instantiate any other by its storyboard ID